# DJ doesn't deserialize an unsaved ActiveRecord model workaround

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, delayed-job

The main problem is that my email does not send

I use rails 3.2.19 with 'delayed_job_mongoid"

To send email i use

```
UserMailer.delay.question(@question)
```

in my database there is registered the delayed job but with error

```
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound, class: ContactForm, primary key:
54418fe3c4bff8bb17000008 (Problem: Document(s) not found for class 
ContactForm with id(s) 54418fe3c4bff8bb17000008.
Summary:
When calling ContactForm.find with an id or array of ids, each 
parameter must match a document in the database or this error
will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 
54418fe3c4bff8bb17000008 ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found:  
54418fe3c4bff8bb17000008.
Resolution:
Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error 
configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of
raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents
when searching for multiples.)
```

So my delayed job doesnt have access co ContactForm.class or to file that should be rendered

Should I required it someway in my initializers/delayed_job.rb ? How can I achive that ? ContactForm.class is in the model directory

Comment: What's the whole error message? `DocumentNotFound` indicates that the *document* can't be found, not the class. That would suggest that your DJ has an invalid or missing `_id`.

Comment: @muistooshort What does it mean ?

Comment: It means that `@question.id` is `54418fe3c4bff8bb17000008` when you `UserMailer.delay.question(@question)` but there is no `ContactForm` with the `id` when the delayed job runs. So what destroys `ContactForm`s?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So this is my fault. I didnt read documentation carefuly...

**DJ doesn't deserialize an unsaved ActiveRecord model**
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/common-problems

This is workaround for it
http://www.kiprosh.com/blog/171

I end up with

controller

```
require "PassingData"

class EmailsController < ApplicationController

    def ask_question

        @question = ContactForm.new(params)

        if @question.valid?

          contact_data = PassingData.serialize(@question)
          UserMailer.delay.question(contact_data)

       render stuff
    end
end
```

mailer

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "email@email.com"

    def question(record)
      @record = PassingData.deserialize(record)
      mail(from: @record.email, to: "email@email.com", subject: 'Something')
  end
end
```

Then in my config/initializers/delayed_job.rb I required

```
require 'contact_form'
require 'PassingData'
```